# setHintQuery does not work in searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I created searchView like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/root"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:queryHint="Hint text"



app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="..."
    local:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    local:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

I've a `toolbar` which has a button on one side and `searchView` on other (using constraints). It shows correctly as I want, but when I try to set hint, I get problems.

```
mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);     
mSearchView.setQueryHint("TEST");
```

When I print out `Log.d(TAG, "test: "+mSearchView.getQueryHint());`, I get desired result "TEST", but what is weird, that in `SearchView` queryHint is "Search..." (visually seen)

Comment: You have to set the adapter first, then the hint will  be visible, try it

Comment: Adapter? Huh.. Can u expand on the reason behind it with an example, please? When I used different approach, I had `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` then setting query was not a problem (now I create SearchView in xml so it complains about compability - I can not use v7.support)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mSearchView.setIconified(false);
```

Comment: why searchview width and height 0dp ?